# First record date need to assign to second record ,if it is no_id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
CREATE TABLE HIST   
(
    ACCT_ID INT,
    ACCT_SEQ INT,
    HISTORY_SEQ INT,
    ACCT_STATUS CHAR(1),
    ASSIGNED_DATE DATETIME,
    EXPIRED_DATE DATETIME,
    ID VARCHAR(50)  
)

INSERT INTO HIST VALUES 
(101,   1,  1,'A','1/12/2015 15:40','1/13/2015 8:00','NO_ID'),
(101,   1,  2,'A','1/13/2015 8:00','3/3/2017 19:43','9596025'),
(101,   1,  3,'A','3/3/2017 19:43',NULL,'9596025')

SELECT * FROM HIST
```

But If id as 'NO_ID',we need to update next row assigned date with first record 
assigned date.

Please find blow image and advice the SQL Server query

[image]

Comment: Please include this data directly in your question, as _text_.  Also, add a description of the logic behind your query.

Comment: What you have tried can you share for easy and fast help?

Comment: CREATE TABLE HIST
 (
  ACCT_ID INT
  ,ACCT_SEQ INT
  ,HISTORY_SEQ INT
  ,ACCT_STATUS CHAR(1)
  ,ASSIGNED_DATE DATETIME
  ,EXPIRED_DATE DATETIME
  ,ID VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO HIST 
VALUES 
(101, 1, 1,'A','1/12/2015 15:40','1/13/2015 8:00','NO_ID'),
(101, 1, 2,'A','1/13/2015 8:00','3/3/2017 19:43','9596025'),
(101, 1, 3,'A','3/3/2017 19:43',NULL,'9596025')

SELECT * FROM HIST

Comment: CREATE TABLE HIST  (ACCT_ID INT,ACCT_SEQ INT,HISTORY_SEQ INT,ACCT_STATUS CHAR(1),ASSIGNED_DATE DATETIME,EXPIRED_DATE DATETIME,ID VARCHAR(50) )
INSERT INTO HIST VALUES (101, 1, 1,'A','1/12/2015 15:40','1/13/2015 8:00','NO_ID'),(101, 1, 2,'A','1/13/2015 8:00','3/3/2017 19:43','9596025'),(101, 1, 3,'A','3/3/2017 19:43',NULL,'9596025')

SELECT * FROM HIST 
But If id as 'NO_ID',we need to update next row assigned date with first record assigned date.

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, we are here to help you solve problems you've already tried to solve yourself an failed - so we need to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Find below query will help you.

```
CREATE TABLE #HIST   
(
    ACCT_ID INT,
    ACCT_SEQ INT,
    HISTORY_SEQ INT,
    ACCT_STATUS CHAR(1),
    ASSIGNED_DATE DATETIME,
    EXPIRED_DATE DATETIME,
    ID VARCHAR(50)  
)

INSERT INTO #HIST VALUES 

(101,   1,  1,'A','1/12/2015 15:40','1/13/2015 8:00','NO_ID'),
(101,   1,  2,'A','1/13/2015 8:00','3/3/2017 19:43','9596025'),
(101,   1,  3,'A','3/3/2017 19:43',NULL,'9596025'),
(102,   1,  4,'A','1/18/2015 15:40','1/13/2015 8:00','NO_ID'),
(102,   1,  5,'A','1/15/2015 8:00','3/3/2017 19:43','9596025'),
(102,   1,  6,'A','3/3/2017 19:43',NULL,'9596025')


SELECT * 
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by ACCT_ID order by HISTORY_SEQ asc) as RID
INTO #ResultID
FROM #HIST  

UPDATE H
SET H.ASSIGNED_DATE=R.ASSIGNED_DATE
FROM #ResultID R
INNER JOIN #ResultID R1 ON R.ACCT_ID=R1.ACCT_ID   and R.RID= R1.RID-1
INNER JOIN #HIST H ON H.ACCT_ID=R1.ACCT_ID AND H.HISTORY_SEQ=R1.HISTORY_SEQ
WHERE R.ID='NO_ID'

select * from #HIST where ID<>'NO_ID'

drop table #HIST   
drop table #ResultID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure SP_Hist
as
begin

DECLARE @I INT=(SELECT Count(*) FROM HIST where Id='NO_ID' );
START:                -- DO
If @I>0
begin
update HIST set ASSIGNED_DATE=(select top 1 ASSIGNED_DATE from HIST where id='NO_ID') where Id=(select top 1 Id from HIST where id !='NO_ID') and HISTORY_SEQ=2

delete HIST where Id='No_ID' and ACCT_ID=(select top 1 ACCT_ID from HIST where id='NO_ID')
end

  SET @I=(SELECT Count(*) FROM HIST where Id='NO_ID');

IF @I!=0 GOTO START; 

end

exec SP_Hist
```